# Exponential inequality (n as exponent and as base)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

everyone. Humbly requesting your help solving the following inequality:
$2^n - n^2 > n^4 + n^2$

Unfortunately,  I cannot understand the principle (so I do not need an answer as much as I need to understand how to solve this kind of inequalities in general).

Comment: You could use induction, but sometimes it is very hard.

Answer (score 1):

You want to know the domain in which the function
$$f(n)=2^n - 2n^2 - n^4 $$ is positive.
Use inspection
$$f(-1)=-\frac 52 \qquad f(0)=1 \qquad f(1)=-1$$ If $n$ is an integer, the domain seems to be very limited.

Comment: Intuitively, I understand that this inequality should be true for most positive n, since 2^n grows faster than n^4. Using trial and error I was able to find out that f(n)=2^n−2n^2−n^4 is positive for n>16, however I was hoping there is some method that helps solving this kind of inequalities without resorting to brute force.